# Working With RSS Feeds in Windows Phone

Tags: xml, windows-phone-7, data-binding, rss

Hello Every One I am working on App to display some Rss Feeds Data in Windows Phone

For Example I have Some Rss feeds Like

[Link's](http://www.sakshieducation.com/(S(3mpuan55nrnw3445zhezkerv))/RSS.aspx)

from this Rss Feeds I like to Display data in My windows Phone App

Problem is when i go through this Links i am Getting some Xml data.I dont Know How to Work with Xml data in Windows phone Apps..

please give me some suggestion's ....Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [SyndicationFeed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.syndication.syndicationfeed(v=vs.110).aspx) class 
and the code example is below

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
String str = await client.GetStringAsync(new Uri("http://yourwebsite.com/test.xml"));
SyndicationFeed feed = new SyndicationFeed();
feed.Load(str);

foreach (SyndicationItem item in feed.Items)
{
  // Extract the information from the SyndicationItem object ....


}
```